# How to work with Lexity changes to Yahoo hosting

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web-hosting

So I have a application running on yahoo hosting for few years now (since 2008) and I used extensive AJAX in the application. Not jQuery or any other ajax frameworks, but I post data from forms and then get AJAX responses from server.

Recently yahoo added a "feature" called "live web insights". It basically adds some javascript to every response from the server including all my ajax responses. This totally screws up my processing on the browser side. There is no way to turn this "feature" off from yahoo hosting.

I was wondering whether anyone has ran into this before or how to fix this.

Comment: This is probably a good question but I changed the title to something more appropriate (otherwise you'd get guaranteed close votes).

Comment: Ah! Couldn't help. Thanks Joe

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Comment: Sure, Here is what one of my alert statement shows. Here I am only expecting the "retval" value "true", but I get this instead `retval : true<script type="text/javascript">(function (d, w) {var x = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0];var f = function () {var s = d.createElement('SCRIPT');s.type = 'text/javascript';s.async = true;s.src = "//np.lexity.com/embed/YW/edc0fbecfab2d012c3b6e2b7c9fb61fb?id=34356436ad6b4e";x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);};w.attachEvent ? w.attachEvent('onload',f) :w.addEventListener('load',f,false);}(document, window));</script>`

Comment: What Content Type is your response? I don't know anything about Lexity, but I would imagine it only tries to inject that into HTML. Have you tried setting the header `Content-Type: application/javascript` in your response?

Comment: I don't set the content-type, so the default is text/html. I was hoping to get this fixed without any code changes.

Comment: It's a simple change to make. I think that's your only option, assuming you weren't able to switch it off in some kind of control panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Lexity, but it looks like it's injecting a script tag into your response. Logic would dictate that they only inject this into HTML responses.

Your response seems to be just

```
true
```

Try setting the `Content-Type: application/javascript` in the response, or perhaps `Content-Type: applicatoin/json`. It's meaningless to inject script tags into those content types. Lexity should detect that header and respect it.

(If it can't, you should probably look elsewhere for hosting.)

Comment: Thanks, I kind of figured that, but there are way too many places to make that change. But I guess that's what I will have to do.

Comment: Good luck. Tick this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Cool. I was expecting to fix this without code change, but I am not going to wait any longer. I added header before every response and got rid of the javascript.